# Selecting a value in a RadioButtonList from data in a Repeater control

Tags: asp.net

I have a repeater control, and inside it I have two radio buttons selecting Sex (male, female).
When I save the page, I save the selected value, either "M" or "F", into the data. When I load the page, I want the radio button to be selected based on what's saved.

So, in this case, my repeater has (Container.DataItem).Sex, which equals 'M' or 'F'. How can I use this data in my radiobuttons to select the appropriate value?

This is the kind of function I'd like to use (but it doesn't exist):

```
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# ((Dependent)(Container.DataItem)).Sex %>' />
```

Please note that I am unable to manipulate the radio buttons in the codebehind because I do not have access to the individual repeater items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is use 2 `RadioButton` control (1 for Female, 1 for Male).

Then specify the `GroupName` in order to unselect one when the other is selected.
Let's say `GroupName="Sex"`.

Then specify when each control should be checked according to your `DataItem`:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="radioMale" runat="server" GroupName="Sex" Checked="<%# ((Dependent)(Container.DataItem)).Sex == 'M' %>" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="radioFemale" runat="server" GroupName="Sex" Checked="<%# ((Dependent)(Container.DataItem)).Sex == 'F' %>" />
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the solution closest to what I was aiming for.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this answer here [Setting selected value on a dropdownlist from codebehind in a repeater in a formview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907291/setting-selected-value-on-a-dropdownlist-from-codebehind-in-a-repeater-in-a-form) you should be able to do something like:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("Sex") %>' />
```

Answer (score 0):

> Please note that I am unable to manipulate the radio buttons in the
>   codebehind because I do not have access to the individual repeater
>   items.

That's what `ItemDataBound` is for...

```
 <asp:Repeater id="Repeater1" OnItemDataBound="repeaterDatabound" runat="server">
```

And on code behind:

```
protected void repeaterDatabound(object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        (e.Item.FindControl("Repeater1") as RadioButtonList).SelectedValue=((Dependent)e.Item.DataItem).Sex.ToString();
    }
}
```