# How do you link a dropdown menu to a database containing products and display these products in ASP?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am trying to create a music store application. On the services (which is the music store actually) page, I created a dropdown list with different music genres. I have managed to bind the dropdown to my database genres. But I cant display the music from the database when I choose a specific option from the dropdown (such as Pop...).

This is how my code looks like for the services.aspx

**Genres**

```
                <hr class="hrsmallleft wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="600ms" />
            </div>

                <div><strong>POP SONGS</strong></div>


    <div>
    <asp:DropDownList id="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Genre" DataValueField="Name" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDown1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
        <asp:ListItem>--Select a Genere--</asp:ListItem>

    </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RegisterConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [MusicRecord]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

    </div>

    <br />
    <br />

       <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-success wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="600ms">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4>
                    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i>Katy Perry - Prism</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>
                    <img src="img/katpop.jpg" height="250" width="294"/>

               </p>
                 <br />
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success">Learn More</asp:HyperLink>

            </div>
            </div>
        </div>               
            <!-- 1st content -->
            <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-success wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="600ms">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4>
                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i>Katy Perry - Prism</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>
                       <img src="img/katpop.jpg" height="250" width="294"/>

                    </p>
                    <br />
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success">Learn More</asp:HyperLink>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-success wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="600ms">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4>
                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i>Katy Perry - Prism</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>
                       <img src="img/katpop.jpg" height="250" width="294"/>

                    </p>
                    <br />
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success">Learn More</asp:HyperLink>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-success wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="600ms">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4>
                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i>Katy Perry - Prism</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>
                       <img src="img/katpop.jpg" height="250" width="294"/>

                    </p>
                    <br />
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success">Learn More</asp:HyperLink>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-success wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="600ms">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4>
                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i>Katy Perry - Prism</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>
                       <img src="img/katpop.jpg" height="250" width="294"/>

                    </p>
                    <br />
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink5" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success">Learn More</asp:HyperLink>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-success wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="600ms">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4>
                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i>Katy Perry - Prism</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>
                       <img src="img/katpop.jpg" height="250" width="294"/>

                    </p>
                    <br />
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink6" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success">Learn More</asp:HyperLink>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add a selected value property to the drop down list

```
 <asp:DropDownList id="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Genre" DataValueField="Name" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDown1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("Name") %>'>
    <asp:ListItem>--Select a Genere--</asp:ListItem>
```

Comment: Adding a selectedvalue to the dropdown just gives me build errors

Comment: then try to add selected value in code behind...on page_Load  like      "DropDownList1.SelectedValue=DropDownList1.Items.FindByValue("Name").Tostring(); "

Comment: Gives me this 
Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error CS1061 'ListItem' does not contain a definition for 'Tostring' and no extension method 'Tostring' accepting a first argument of type 'ListItem' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) modern-business(2) C:\Users\mahmoud\Documents\Software Engineering UWE\Visual-Studio-files\visual-studio-Projects\Spotify-Music-Store-16oct_1156\Spotify Music Store\modern-business\services.aspx.cs 19

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907291/setting-selected-value-on-a-dropdownlist-from-codebehind-in-a-repeater-in-a-form]

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you get rid of the SQL datasource control. Add Entity Framework to your project. Run LINQ query and bind results to DropdownList. Then "OnSelectedIndexChanged" event run another LINQ query to extract data from your database.

```
using (var rep = new efEntities()){
     var results= rep.Genre.ToList();
     // bind
     DropDownList1.datasource=results;
     DropDownList1.DataTextField="";
     DropDownList1.DataValueField="";
     DropDownList1.DataBind();
}

protected void DropDownList1_selectedindexChanged(){
    int genreID = convert.toint32(DropDownList1.selectedvalue);
    // search database
    using (var rep = new efEntities()){
    var results = rep.Music.Where(m=>m.genreID==genreID).ToList();

    // loop to get results
    foreach(var item in results){
        //do stuff
}
}
}
```